# Error JavaFX con Maven: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec (default-cli) on project

Tags: javafx, maven, exec-maven-plugin

estoy desarrollando un proyecto utilizando JavaFX con Maven. Al tratar de ejecutar el archivo main de la GUI el IDE de NetBeans me arroja el error que está en el titulo de este hilo.

Este es el codigo del archivo main

```
package com.myproject.escritorioreclutamiento4_0fx.model;

import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Principal extends Application {
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../src/main/resources/fxml.FXMLLogIn.fxml"));
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
}
```

Aquí una parte del pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>19</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>19</maven.compiler.target>
        <exec.mainClass>com.myproject.escritorioreclutamiento4_0fx.model.Principal</exec.mainClass>
    </properties>
```

Estuve leyendo los hilos relacionados a este error donde mencionan que el problema se puede arreglar modificando el "exec.mainClass", en este caso ese detalle ya ha sido corregido.

Este es el pom.xml completo

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>EscritorioReclutamiento4_0FX</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>19</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>19</maven.compiler.target>
        <exec.mainClass>com.myproject.escritorioreclutamiento4_0fx.model.Principal</exec.mainClass>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.31</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.myproject.escritorioreclutamiento4_0fx.model.Principal</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for manual attach debugging -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run@debug -->
                        <id>debug</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                                <option>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=localhost:8000</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for automatic IDE debugging -->
                        <id>ide-debug</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                                <option>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=${jpda.address}</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for automatic IDE profiling -->
                        <id>ide-profile</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg1}</option>
                                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg2}</option>
                                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg3}</option>
                                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg4}</option>
                                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg5}</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**ACTUALIZACION**

He estado revisando la página de http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html y al parecer lo que tengo que hacer es adaptar alguno de los dos códigos acorde a mis necesidades, de igual manera ya he estado probando con el de "Exec Goal" aunque de momento no he hecho que se ejecute el programa. Cuando logre hacer que se ejecute les estaré avisando.

Muchas gracias por su tiempo y ayuda :)

Comment: ¿Tienes el plugin `org.codehaus.mojo` en el POM? Pulsa en [edit] y muestra cómo lo tienes. Estará en un apartado `<plugin>`, revisa.

Comment: Listo @A.Cedano.

Comment: puedes correrlo habilitando excepciones y poner el mensaje de error completo? por el titulo se ve que ya obtuviste el mensaje de error que geenra maven y alli te explica como correlo en debug y excepciones

Comment: Acabo de crear un proyecto de prueba, el cual si puedo ejecutar desde consola con el comando `mvn clean javafx:run` ya intenté dejar la configuración por defecto del pom del proyecto con el que estoy trabajando y sigue sin ejecutar jaja, creo que voy a copiar y pegar todo en otro proyecto, haber si así se soluciona. @RuslanLópez